Cannot authenticate in fresh installed Laravel 11 with MySQL/MariaDB
I cannot have Laravel 11 authentication working with MySQL or MariaDB.
Here's what I've done:

Install Laravel with composer create-project laravel/laravel foo
Create Database and edit .env accordingly (connection is ok)
Install Laravel/Fortify with composer require laravel/fortify
Migrate the DB with default seeder (user: test@example.com/password)
Created a basic login form and a basic home view which displays user name when logged in
Put a basic logout form on home page
Check a million times that @csrf is present in login and logout forms (it is)

Here's what happens when I test in a browser:

When I try to log in with the test user, I'm not logged in, but I'm correctly redirected to the appropriate page configured in Fortify.

When I try to log in with the test user and the remember checkbox, I do log in. But I cannot log out, I get a 419 page expired error.
That's weird.
Here's weirer:

If I use SQLite, there is no problem: I can log in and out.

If I use MySQL/MariaDB and file session driver, there is no problem either: I can log in and out too.


So, here's what works or not:



Database
Session driver
Remember me
Log in
Log out




MySQL / MariaDB
database
no
no
n/a


MySQL / MariaDB
database
yes
yes
no


MySQL / MariaDB
file
yes / no
yes
yes


SQLite
database
yes / no
yes
yes


SQLite
file
yes / no
yes
yes



I have found nothing about such a problem (Laravel authentication with MySQL/MariaDB combined to session database driver) neither on SO nor in Laravel issues.
I'm running:

Ubuntu 23.10
PHP 8.3.8
MariaDB Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.11.8-MariaDB
Laravel 11.12 with Fortify 1.21.3


This reads to me more like a bug report, ratjer than a question we can answer to. You need to share relevamt code with us if you think this is still a coding error on your side

Thanks for your answer, i've found the problem...

One thing I forgot to mention: I use UUID for users. Therefore, session table needs to be created accordingly:
Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // ...
            $table->foreignUuid('user_id')->nullable()->index();

